# How can I start a test after the component renders?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a component, but my tests are always failing because they start before the component renders, my tests only recognize the component elements a few seconds later.

I tried to use a setTimeOut and it works, but it's bad practice, because I don't know the exact time when the component finishes to render, so I would like to find a solution to change that. I'm using the react testing library.

My test:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Component from '../components/Component/Component';
import React from 'react'
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';

let props = {
    reorderList: jest.fn(),
}

const setup = () => {
    const utils = render(<Component {...props} />)

    const reorder = utils.queryByTestId("reorder")
    return {
        reorder,
        ...utils,
    }
}

describe('Example Component', () => {

    test('Test', async () => {
            const { reorder } = setup()
            ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(reorder)
            expect(props.reorderList).toBeCalled()
    })
});
```

My component

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

...

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData() //Set isLoaded to true after the data is fetched
}, [])

...

if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="rows">
                <div className="filter">
                   <button id="reorder" onClick={(e) => { reorderList() }}>Reorder</button>
                </div>
                <div className="main">
                    {render()}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you read https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/

Comment: Yes, I've read about waitFor, but I had some problems trying to implement that, I don't know where specifically the waitFor should be

Comment: You could probably ask a better question by showing a [mre] of that, then. The short answer is it should be between rendering the component and needing to access something that's not present on initial render.